# PHP GD: make pink transparent (base64)

Tags: php, image, colors, base64, transparent

Okay. My script allows people to upload images via JavaScript in base64.
Everything goes okay, except one thing. Images can have a pink (255,0,255) pink background. That pink background should be converted to transparent (before inserting in the database). But when I save it in my database (in base64), the background is still pink.

$tile is the base64 of the image (obviously).

```
function imagetobase64 ($img)
{
    if (!is_resource($img))
        return "";

    ob_start();
    imagepng($img);
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return base64_encode($content);
}

$tile = str_replace(' ', '+', $tile); // Because spaces in the JavaScript should be + in PHP

$img = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($tile));
imagesavealpha($img, true);
$pink = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 255);
imagecolortransparent($img, $pink);
$tile = imagetobase64($img);
imagedestroy($img);
// Here the query etc.
```

Feel free to ask more details if needed.

Comment: Are you sure `imagesavealpha($img,true)` - ie, save full alpha info - is what you want?  You want a single transparent color here, not a full alpha channel?  Also, imagesavealpha and imagecolortransparent can return errors, might be useful to at least evaluate these return values.

Comment: @fvu Well, they can upload images with a transparent background too. I also tried it without `imagesavealpha`, with `imagealphablending`, ... Nothing worked.